# Discordpy CheckFailure: The check functions for command test failed

Tags: python, discord.py

I followed the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) nearly verbatim with my code, but in my console displays a `CheckFailure` when the user is not an admin (i.e. when `predicate` returns `False`). Nothing gets displayed when it returns `True`. Why do I receive this error, and how can I fix it so that it doesn't show the error? From my understanding, it shouldn't show an error to begin with.

```py
def is_admin_role():
    async def predicate(ctx):
        admin_roles = [admin_role_id, admin_role_test_id]
        role_list = [x for x in ctx.message.author.roles] # get list of roles
        role_id_list = [x.id for x in role_list] # get their id's

        # false = user doesn't have admin role, true = user has admin role.
        has_admin_role = any(item in admin_roles for item in role_id_list)
            
        if not has_admin_role:
            # Create an embed to let the user know they can't run this command.
            embed = utils.ErrorEmbed("You must be an admin to run this command.")
            await ctx.send(embed = embed.print()) # Send the embed.
            return False # Return false since the user can't run it.
        return True # User is able to run it

    return commands.check(predicate)

@bot.command()
@is_admin_role()
async def test(ctx):
    ...
    # do whatever this code does.
```

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 125, in on_command_error
    raise error
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 851, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 779, in prepare
    raise CheckFailure('The check functions for command {0.qualified_name} failed.'.format(self))
discord.ext.commands.errors.CheckFailure: The check functions for command test failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

If the check func returns a `False`, `commands.CheckFailure` is raised (you can catch it in the error handler). If it returns a `True` the command is invoked, from the docs:

> When an error happens, the error is propagated to the error handlers. If you do not raise a custom `CommandError` derived exception, then it will get wrapped up into a `CheckFailure` exception.