# How do I fix commands check error in discordpy?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So it seems that my check is not working, I believe the function is setup correctly but I may be wrong how should I go about fixing this error?

```
@client.command()
@commands.check(is_server_owner)
async def serversetup(guild,ctx):
  await guild.create_role(name='safe')
  await ctx.send('Please put the safe role above the AntiNuke role so those people will not be punished by the antinuke! | Server is setup!')
```

Here is the error I am getting

```
Ignoring exception in command serversetup:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/AntiNuke/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/AntiNuke/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/AntiNuke/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 778, in prepare
    raise CheckFailure('The check functions for command {0.qualified_name} failed.'.format(self))
discord.ext.commands.errors.CheckFailure: The check functions for command serversetup failed.
```

Here is the is_server_owner function

```
def is_server_owner(ctx):
    return ctx.message.author.id == ctx.guild.owner
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discordpy CheckFailure: The check functions for command test failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67111089/discordpy-checkfailure-the-check-functions-for-command-test-failed)

Comment: No not really, I am running this in a server I am the owner of so I do not know why it would return a False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your `check` you check whether the `id` of the author is the same as the object of the guild owner, so it will always return `false`. To fix this, simply change `ctx.message.author.id` to `ctx.message.author`.

Comment: or change `ctx.guild.owner` to `ctx.guild.owner_id`